# grep with negation in pattern

Tags: grep, regular-expression

How to use `grep` (or another tool) to match with negation parts in pattern?

example

```
php cronjob.php test
php cronjob.php scan_document
php cronjob.php scan_document -v
php cronjob.php scan_documenttest -v
php cronjob.php scan_document_callback_retry
```

From the scenario above I need to match line 2 and 3

```
php cronjob.php scan_document
php cronjob.php scan_document -v
```

I use this command

```
ps --noheader -o pid,ppid,cmd -C php | grep "cronjob.php scan_document"
```

But it matches more than I want

```
php cronjob.php scan_document
php cronjob.php scan_document -v
php cronjob.php scan_document_callback_retry
```

Comment: Just use the `-w` option. `grep -w 'cronjob.php scan_document' file`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you want to match all the cases where there is a *word boundary* `\b` after `scan_document`:

```
$ grep 'cronjob\.php scan_document\b' << EOF
php cronjob.php test
php cronjob.php scan_document
php cronjob.php scan_document -v
php cronjob.php scan_documenttest -v
php cronjob.php scan_document_callback_retry
EOF
php cronjob.php scan_document
php cronjob.php scan_document -v
```

Note that I escaped the period in `cronjob.php` - otherwise it may match any single character.

Comment: ahh great.. didn't know `\b` was supported by grep

Answer (score 0):

Your `grep` is doing its job, your pattern doesn't tell nothing about how the string ends. You have to add it then:

```bsh
$ grep "cronjob\.php scan_document$\|cronjob\.php scan_document[[:blank:]].*$" file
php cronjob.php scan_document
php cronjob.php scan_document -v
```

---

We are feeding `grep` with two patterns, one the end of the line `$` and the other a space and what follows `[[:blank:]].*$`.

Comment: have added one more example..

Comment: It must not match something like `php cronjob.php scan_documenttest -v` either

Comment: @clarkk could you define exactly what criteria should follow `...document`? Just the end, a space, just `-v`?

Comment: the first argument sent to the php script (eg. scan_document) must be an exact match but there can be more trailing arguments..

Answer (score 0):

The first argument to the php script must equal `scan_document`:5

```
$ awk '$3 == "scan_document"' file
php cronjob.php scan_document
php cronjob.php scan_document -v
```